# AWS CDK Nodejs 16 lambda bundling not working

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

Recently updated all lambda functions from nodejs 12 to 16. Now the problem seems to be with bundling. I need some extra packages as well as openssl for the bundle but it seems the Docker images for bundling have changed somehow between versions. Here is my cdk:

```
const layer = new lambda.LayerVersion(this, `test-layer`, {
  code: lambda.Code.fromDockerBuild(__dirname, {}),
  compatibleRuntimes: [lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_16_X],
  license: 'Apache-2.0',
  description: 'A test layer',
});

const sendLambda = new lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction(this, 'test-lambda', {
  entry: 'lambda/test.ts',
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
  timeout: cdk.Duration.minutes(1),
  vpc,
  bundling: {
    nodeModules: ['got'],
    environment: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production',
    },
    commandHooks: {
      afterBundling (inputDir: string, outputDir: string): string[] {
        return [`cp -fr ${inputDir}/config ${outputDir}`];
      },
      beforeBundling (_inputDir: string, _outputDir: string): string[] {
        return [];
      },
      beforeInstall (_inputDir: string, _outputDir: string): string[] {
        return ['yum -y install openssl11-devel || true'];
      }
    }
  },
  layers: [layer],
  memorySize: 512,
  environment: {
    APP_ENVIRONMENT: props.envName,
  },
  logRetention: logs.RetentionDays.TWO_MONTHS,
});
```

When running cdk synth, the yum install would fail without piping it out with:

```
You need to be root to perform this command.
```

And installation of node_modules fails:

```
npm WARN logfile could not be created: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/tmp/npm-cache/_logs/2022-08-30T13_21_35_965Z-debug-0.log'
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.
npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an
npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.
npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password at:
npm ERR!     https://www.npmjs.com/forgot
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are
npm ERR! probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login
```

Any ideas what could cause this problem between the version upgrade? Apparently bunding is using public.ecr.aws/sam/build-nodejs16.x:latest image.